# python package installed in pipenv but says no module found

Tags: python, flask

I install flask with pipenv, but cannot import the package.

python 3.6.8, pipenv 2018.11.26

```sh
$ pipenv install flask
Installing flask…
Adding flask to Pipfile's [packages]…
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (a18377)…
✔ Installation Succeeded 
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 29/29 — 00:00:0603
(env) $ python -c 'import flask'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

But looks like flask is installed:

```sh
(env) $ flask --help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../.virtualenvs/env-vop2XA0b/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 529, in list_commands
    rv.update(info.load_app().cli.list_commands(ctx))
  File ".../virtualenvs/env-vop2XA0b/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 384, in load_app
    'Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide '
flask.cli.NoAppException: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory.
Usage: flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  A general utility script for Flask applications.

  Provides commands from Flask, extensions, and the application. Loads the
  application defined in the FLASK_APP environment variable, or from a
  wsgi.py file. Setting the FLASK_ENV environment variable to 'development'
  will enable debug mode.

    $ export FLASK_APP=hello.py
    $ export FLASK_ENV=development
    $ flask run

Options:
  --version  Show the flask version
  --help     Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  routes  Show the routes for the app.
  run     Runs a development server.
  shell   Runs a shell in the app context.
```

and

```sh
(env) $ which flask
path/to/.virtualenvs/env-vop2XA0b/bin/flask
```

I get same behavior with `virtualenv`

what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are installing the package using pipenv, however, you have to enter the virtual environment created by pipenv to actually use the packages installed.

First, install the package using `pipenv install flask`

Now, you have two options to run anything in the virtual environment with flask installed.

1. `pipenv run flask` - which will directly run flask command, without the need for you to source the virtual environment.
2. `pipenv shell` and `python -c 'import flask'` - which will work exactly like virtual environment, by sourcing the virtual environment and then running using the python of it.

Comment: `(env) $`  indicates active venv created by pipenv

Comment: It appears that I am unable to reciprocate the same error with the Python version 3.6.8 and Pipenv version 2018.11.26.

Comment: what is wierd is that I am getting same issue with virtualevironment created with `virtualenv` package